# Insert to specific Sheet Name based on form input data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanted to insert my data to a specific sheet name based on form input value of "svdate":

```html
<form method="get" action="submission-success.php" name="google-sheet">

        <div class="form-group">Customer Name:
            <input type="text" name="Customer" class="form-control" value="Michael Wilson" required readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">Total:
            <input type="text" name="Amount" class="form-control" value="$120.00" required readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">Cleaner Name:
            <input type="text" name="Cleaners" class="form-control" value="Dee" required readonly />
        </div>
        

        <div>
            <input type="text" name="svdate" class="form-control" value="06/17/2021" required readonly hidden />
        </div>

     <! –– some other fields here -->

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="" id="qid" class="button" onclick="this.classList.toggle('button--loading')">
                <span class="button__text">Submit</span>
            </button> 
        </div>
</form>
```

Here are our sheet names which are all based on dates:

[image]

Since the svdate on our form is 06/17/2021, the form data should be inserted to 6/17 sheetname. How can I do it?

Here's my script in Code.gs to insert data but I don't know how to assign the value to my sheetName variable:

```
var sheetName = // I want to assign the "svdate" value here...

    var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

    function intialSetup () {
      var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
    }

    function doPost (e) {
      var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
      lock.tryLock(10000)

      try {
        var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
        var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

        var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 10).getValues()[0]
        var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

        var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
          return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
        })
        
        var find = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(newRow[0]).matchEntireCell(true).findNext(); // Added
        sheet.getRange(find ? find.getRow() : nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow]); // Added
        
        return ContentService
        .createTextOutput(e.parameter.callback + "(" + JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow })+ ")")
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
      }

      catch (e) {
        return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(e.parameter.callback + "(" + JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e })+ ")")
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT)
      }

      finally {
        lock.releaseLock()
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that in your situation, it is required to retrieve `6/17` from `06/17/2021`. For this, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this case, please modify `doPost` as follows.

#### From:

```
try {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)
```

#### To:

```
try {
  sheetName = e.parameter.svdate.split("/").splice(0, 2).map(e => e.replace(/^0/, "")).join("/");
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'));
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (!sheet) throw new Error(`${sheetName} was not found.`);
```

- In this modified script, when the sheet name of `sheetName` is not found in the Spreadsheet, an error `${sheetName} was not found.` is returned.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this at the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".
- This answer supposes that your current script works fine. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: It throws this error: Syntax error. (line 15, file "customer")Dismiss

Comment: @geeksified Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your error message of `Syntax error. (line 15, file "customer")`, I'm worry that your script before my modification point is not reflected might not work OR you might have miscopied my script. How about this? Because in my proposed modification, only the sheet name is created and checked it. If you cannot find the point, can you provide the whole script for replicating your issue? Because from your error message, I cannot understand about the error line. By this, I would like to confirm your current issue.

Comment: Hi Tanaike. Thank you again and again. My code works fine with your help since yesterday. I was able to post on a specific sheet with only var sheetName = e.parameter.svdate while renaming sheet names as mm/dd/yyyy format ie. "06/17/2021". But if my sheet names are setup as m/dd, your added modification var sheetName = e.parameter.svdate.split("/").splice(0, 2).map(e => e.replace(/^0/, "")).join("/") I cannot save it anymore. It has that error above when I try to save it. I will try to find a way so you can replicate it. Thanks again.

Comment: I can see that your code modification works fine outside of my script. It does replace from 06/17/2021 to 6/17. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to save my .gs script with your code modification in it. It throws that error when I try to save it.

Comment: Also, the throw part has this error: Illegal character. (line 18, file "customer")Dismiss

Comment: @geeksified Thank you for replying. From your replying, if the error line of 18 is `sheetName = e.parameter.svdate.split("/").splice(0, 2).map(e => e.replace(/^0/, "")).join("/");`, I'm worry that you might disable V8 runtime. If it's so, please modify it to `sheetName = e.parameter.svdate.split("/").splice(0, 2).map(function(e){return e.replace(/^0/, "")}).join("/");` and test it again? Or, can you enable V8 runtime with the script editor? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime)

Comment: I am so grateful you're always here! It works fine now! Turning off V8 and using your code `sheetName = e.parameter.svdate.split("/").splice(0, 2).map(function(e){return e.replace(/^0/, "")}).join("/");`

Comment: @geeksified Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.